# QGIS 2.8 Change Colour of Selected features

Tags: qgis, symbology, qgis-2, select

How can I change the colour of the selected features in QGIS.  The light yellow is not easy to see.

Answer (score 2):

Go to 'Settings->Options'. Under 'Canvas&Legend' you have the opportunity to Change the Default selection colour:
[image]