# QGIS make the appearance of selected feature the same as defined in symbology

Tags: qgis, select, vector-layer

I want to select my item one by one in order to capture them separately.
I defined their colour like blue and thickness as 1.

According the thread below:

[Displaying only selected features on map in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111784/displaying-only-selected-features-on-map-in-qgis)

I could smoothly define the rule and show only selected elements on my map.
However, they appear still as per the default selection settings set in the QGIS options...

[image]

I can admittedly change them easily by following the thread here:

[Is there anyway to modify thickness & color of a selected polygon?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54574/is-there-anyway-to-modify-thickness-color-of-a-selected-polygon)

[QGIS 2.8 Change Colour of Selected features](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170361/qgis-2-8-change-colour-of-selected-features)

but the problem is, that it's going to be applied for all other items/layers concerned in my project, or even the entire QGIS program.

I would like to keep this changed option only for the layer I am working on right now. Is it possible to change the selection options individually for the layer concerned, or shall I go with the general options as discussed in the threads above?

Comment: OK, although there is a lack of the object thickness too. I can only change the colour...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a virtual layer that will display the selected feature.
This virtual layer should be located above the main layer.

1. Add a virtual field to the point layer, of type `integer size 1` and populate it using the expression `is_selected()`

(note: don't use a `boolean` type because of this [bug](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/31798).)

`[image]

So when a line is selected, the value in this field will be set to 1.

2. Create a virtual layer that will display only the selected line.

Go to the menu `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` and enter the following query. Replace the layer name for yours

```sql
select l.*
from lines l 
where  l.selected = 1
```

3. Style this virtual layer as you wish.

When you select a line, you will have to pan the map a bit to refresh the virtual layer.

4. If you want, you can hide the original selection. In the main layer, in the rule-based symbology, un-tick the box beside the "selected" rule. Doing so will let you apply a thin line style on the selected line.