# Change selection color to be just a polygon with no fill in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3

[image]

Can we change this to be no fill color but just a yellow outline?

[image]

Currently stuck in v3.16 but I don't see this in the Dev version either.

Comment: By "stuck in 3.16" do you mean there is something preventing you from updating? This is a feature that has been introduced in 3.34 and can be found under `Layer Properties > Rendering`.

Comment: related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/392493/qgis-make-the-appearance-of-selected-feature-the-same-as-defined-in-symbology/392532#392532

Comment: @Matt just at a corporate IT level. Thanks for pointing out how to access this feature. It will add to my list of reasons why we should be using the current LTR at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So upgrading will solve this as per Matt's workflow and the option suggested in the comment by JGH will also resolve the issue. You can create a virtual layer to handle Point, Line and Polygon selections separately.