# QGIS highlight only parts of the selected feature

Tags: qgis

I am creating a point style in QGIS with raster image marker. The point attribute data contains some picture path and I would like to render/ visualize them when a feature is selected. So far I have a working formula, however when I select the feature the loaded picture will be yellow as well, so I cant quick-view it.. Is there any way to apply the selection highlight just one part of the style or can I use somehow outline selection without fill in?

[image]

Comment: If you are using QGIS 3.34 or above, you can customise the selection symbol by going to the Layer Properties. On the rendering tab look for the `Selections` sections and check `Override symbol for selected features`. You can then make a symbol using all the settings that are available in (Single Symbol) Symbology. For earlier versions of QGIS, [see this Q & A](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/392493/qgis-make-the-appearance-of-selected-feature-the-same-as-defined-in-symbology).

Comment: I am using 3.28, I will have a look, thanks

Comment: @matt can you make that an answer please for future searchers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using QGIS 3.34 or above, you can customise the selection symbol by going to the Layer Properties.

On the rendering tab look for the `Selections` section and check `Override symbol for selected features`.

You can then make a symbol using all the settings that are available in (Single Symbol) Symbology.

For earlier versions of QGIS, see this [Question & Answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/392493/qgis-make-the-appearance-of-selected-feature-the-same-as-defined-in-symbology).